# Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Books)"

Tags: react-native, react-redux

New to react/redux here.

Getting error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Books)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Books)".

I've attached snippet of my code.
To see everything else, please check out my snack.

https://snack.expo.io/@ganiyat1/colorful-thrills

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import MaterialTabs from 'react-native-material-tabs';
import CardFlip from 'react-native-card-flip';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NewReleases } from '../shared/Booklist';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      Booklists: state.Booklists
    };
  };
  
  
  .....
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Books);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your root-node of the app has to wrapped with `Redux` `Provider` like:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from 'your/path/to/redux/store';
...
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Navigator />
  </Provider>
);
```

Then you'll have the right to map any `state` into your component via `connect`

Comment: how do i set up store? I don't have that.

Comment: @BeNice I recommend you follow a complete tutorial on youtube or udemy .... cause `redux` is kind of *advanced* topic